# Possible to package all needed files in an EXE?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I wrote an EXE that uses a third party dll and a template excel document.  Anytime someone uses it they have to copy all three files (which is a pain).

Is there any way I can package everything that is needed into the EXE so there is only one file to worry about?

Answer (score 2):

This is something that [ilmerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en) is used for, atleast for combining assemblies. There is more information [here](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/leveraging-ilmerge-to-simplify-deployment-and-your-users-experience/) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mergingassemblies.aspx).

There are several known problems with this though.

Comment: @Abe - That's correct. You'd have to include that as a resource as shown by the other answers. But you can then use ilmerge to build a single exe.

Answer (score 1):

You can add files to your project in visual studio and set `Build Action` to `None` and `Copy to Output directory` to `Copy  always`.

or

You can add these files to assembly resources. [Adding and Editing Resources (Visual C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

I suggest doing the first.

Also, for 3rd party dll: set `Copy Local` to `true` for the reference.

After you have your project set like this. Create setup project in VS and it will make one exe as you want.

[How to: Create or Add a Setup Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes - drag it into your project resources (My Project > Resources tab) and from there you can access it using `global::Resources.resourceFile` (I think - that might not be the right syntax, an alternative is [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/20907-Resources-C-Express)) as a byte stream and write it locally from there.

Answer (score 0):

Software installation is a pain, but I think you can get away with an xcopy style deployment by using the compression tool of your choice (like winzip) and creating a self extracting executable.